# What does `apply.` tactic on it's own do in Coq -- i.e. without specifying a rule or hypothesis to unify the goal's conclusion with?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I think I understand the main idea of the apply tactic but I can't figure out what it does in this case:

```
Lemma HilbertS : 
  forall A B C : Prop, 
    (A -> B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> A -> C.
  (* A ->(B -> C)*)
Proof.
  move=> A B C. (* since props A B C are the 1st things in the assumption stack, this pops them and puts them in the local context, note using the same name as the proposition name.*)
  move=> hAiBiC hAiB hA. (* pops the first 3 premises from the hypothesis stack with those names into the local context *)
  move: hAiBiC. (* put hAiBiC tactic back *)
apply.
by [].
by apply: hAiB.
Qed.
```

I know that the `apply` tactic receives a hypothesis and matches the conclusion of the hypothesis with conclusion of the subgoal (I assume the current focused subgoal) and if they unify then uses the substitution from the unification to update the premises of the hypothesis as the new subgoal(s). See appendix for details.

However, in the `HilbertS` proof I gave I can't figure out what `apply.` is actually doing and the docs from [the regular tactics in coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.apply) and [the ssreflex in coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#coq:tacn.apply-(ssreflect)) aren't helping.

Note the proof state is:

```
A, B, C: Prop
hAiB: A -> B
hA: A
====
1/1
(A -> B -> C) -> C
```

What is `apply.` doing here if the hypothesis is not even being select? I assume it's unify with something but `C` is not in any of the hypothesis in the local context so it's really confusing me what it's even unifying with. Basically what is `apply.` doing here -- especially without a hypothesis/term argument givent o the tactic apply (in SSReflect)?

---

## Appendix explaining my understanding of apply

```
(* 
https://pjreddie.com/coq-tactics/#apply 

Usually an apply in Isabelle matches the rule's conclusion with the subgoal's 
conclusion, unifies them and if them match then replaces the rules hypothesis
as the things to be proven given the substitution
e.g.
rule1 A1 => A2 => A
subgoal: B1 => B2 => C
apply rule rule. (* replace C with A1 A1 to be proven with the right subtitution*)

sig = Unify(A, C)

new subgoals:
sig(B1) => sig(B2) => sig(A1)
sig(B1) => sig(B2) => sig(A2)

note: notation: proof_state = <local_context, goals>
*)
Lemma modus_ponens:
  forall p q : Prop, 
    (p -> q) -> p -> q.
Proof.
  intros. (*  <H: p -> q, H0: p, q> *)
  apply H. (* matches H cocnlusion q with goal q, replaces p to be proven now *)
  assumption. (* goal p is in the assumption in the local context, so discharge it *)
Qed.

From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
Lemma modus_ponens':
  forall p q : Prop, 
    (p -> q) -> p -> q.
Proof.
  move=> p q p_implies_q p_fact. (* <..., p_fact: p, p_implies)q: p->q, goal=q>*)
  apply: p_implies_q.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3):

The SSReflect documentation you linked says what it does:

> In its defective form, this tactic is a synonym for:
>
> ```
> intro top; first [refine top | refine (top _) | refine (top _ _) | …]; clear top.
> ```
>
> where `top` is a fresh name, and the sequence of `refine` tactics tries to catch the appropriate number of wildcards to be inserted. Note that this use of the refine tactic implies that the tactic tries to match the goal up to expansion of constants and evaluation of subterms.

I.e. `apply.` takes a goal of the form `A -> R` and, in sequence, tries to unify (roughly) `A = R`, `A = H1 -> R`, `A = H1 -> H2 -> R`, etc. until it gets a unification for some `H1`, ..., `Hn` (so the goal looks like `(H1 -> ... -> Hn -> R) -> R`). Then it turns this into subgoals `H1`, ..., `Hn` by using the `H1 -> ... -> Hn -> R` hypothesis to combine the subgoals into the  `R` conclusion. (The actual behavior is more general than this, since it should be able to handle dependent products too.) Or, in short,

```
apply.
```

is basically

```
intros H. apply H; clear H.
```

Comment: Apologies I am not a Coq expert but your answer doesn't make sense to me (nor does the docs of course). But the way I think of unification is that it's a function that tries to "match" two things given as input and returns the substitution that does that. e.g. `Unify(A, B)` where `A, B` are terms. What does it mean to unify `unify (roughly) A = R, A = H1 -> R, A = H1 -> H2 -> R, etc `. Is the equality sign the notation you are using for unify term on the lhs & rhs of the equality?

Comment: also where is Coq getting/generating/synthesising the H's from?

Comment: I see. I think I understand this better. The reason it is trying to unify the assumption `A` with the conclusion `R` (which seemed bizarre to me at first) is because `apply.` actually does an intro at the beginning with `top` being the name. So if I understand refine correctly after it introduces `top` (or your `A`) then it tries to do  partial exact (my way of understanding `refine`). And then if it matches great it either closes the proof or returns the holes where the match didn't fit perfectly between the assumption that was introduced as `top/A` and the conclusion `R` in the original goal

Comment: what does `(top _)` mean?

Comment: why does it do `clear H.`? doesn't removing this from the context maker it potentially "harder" to prove things later?

Comment: Well, when you're unifying expressions `A` and `B`, in order for anything interesting to get done `A` and `B` need to contain unknowns (i.e. unification variables, which Coq calls evars or *e*xistential *var*iables). Unifying `A = B` (yes, I'm using `=`for unification) "solves for" the unknowns and produces a substitution for them. Coq understands `_` to represent such a "hole"/evar in an expression. When Coq processes an expression like `top _ _`, it creates two evars for each `_`: one for the expression itself and one for its type. Then it proceeds with typechecking (1...)

Comment: (1...) which may be able to (partially) fill in the holes. (E.g. for `top : forall n : nat, n <> S n`, checking the expression `fun x : _ => top x _` will result in `fun x : (nat : Set) => top x (_ : x = S n)`.)`) `refine` takes a term, potentially with holes in it/its type, unifies the type with the goal, then turns the remaining evars into goals. In your case, `top : A -> B -> C` and so the `top _` case doesn't work: it has type `B -> C` which doesn't unify with `C`. The `top _ _` case does. Coq creates evars `H1 : Type`, `H2 : Type`, `H3 : H1`, `H4 : H2` (2...)

Comment: (2...) and interprets the expression as `top H3 H4`. Checking this gives it type `C` while requiring the substitution `H1 = A, H2 = B.` `refine` then unifies `C = C` (which succeeds but produces no other data), fills in the current proof hole with `top H3 H4,` then makes the unsolved evars `H3, H4` into new goals (since `H3 : A` and `H4 : B`, those `A` and `B` become the goals you see "below the bar"). And yes, `clear`ing at the end makes the proof "harder." (3...)

Comment: (3...) It's justified, because 1) You didn't specify a name for the new hypothesis, and it's unhygienic (and fragile) to have Coq generate one for you. 2) It's annoying to deal with proof contexts bloated with hypotheses that will not be used going forward; tactics that "consume" hypotheses are convenient to use when possible. 3) If you wanted to keep it, surely you could write `intros H. apply H.` yourself.