# What is the right proof term so that the ssreflect tutorial work with the exact: hAiB example?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I was going through the tutorial https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00407778/document for ssreflect and they have the proof:

```
Variables A B C : Prop.
Hypotheses (hAiBiC : A -> B -> C) (hAiB : A -> B) (hA : A).
Lemma HilbertS2 : 
  C. 
Proof. 
  apply: hAiBiC; first by apply: hA. 
  exact: hAiB. 
Qed.
```

but it doesn't actually work since the goal is

```
B
```

which puzzled me...what is this not working because the coq version changed? Or perhaps something else? What was the exact argument supposed to be anyway?

---

I think I do understand what the `exact` argument does. It completes the current subgoal by making sure the proof term (program) given has the type of the current goal. e.g.

```
Theorem add_easy_induct_1_exact:
forall n:nat,
  n + 0 = n.
Proof.
  exact (fun n : nat =>
nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + 0 = n0) eq_refl
   (fun (n' : nat) (IH : n' + 0 = n') =>
    eq_ind_r (fun n0 : nat => S n0 = S n') eq_refl IH) n).
Qed.
```

for the proof of addition's commutativity.

---

```
Module ssreflect1.

(* Require Import ssreflect ssrbool eqtype ssrnat. *)
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Theorem three_is_three:
  3 = 3.
Proof. by []. Qed.

(* 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388591/what-does-apply-tactic-on-its-own-do-in-coq-i-e-without-specifying-a-rul
*)
Lemma HilbertS : 
  forall A B C : Prop, 
    (A -> B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> A -> C.
  (* A ->(B -> C)*)
Proof.
  move=> A B C. (* since props A B C are the 1st things in the assumption stack, this pops them and puts them in the local context, note using the same name as the proposition name.*)
  move=> hAiBiC hAiB hA. (* pops the first 3 premises from the hypothesis stack with those names into the local context *)
  move: hAiBiC. (* put hAiBiC tactic back *)
apply.
by [].
(* move: hAiB.
apply. *)
by apply: hAiB.
(* apply: hAiB.
by [].dd *)
Qed.

Variables A B C : Prop.
Hypotheses (hAiBiC : A -> B -> C) (hAiB : A -> B) (hA : A).
Lemma HilbertS2 : 
  C. 
Proof. 
  apply: hAiBiC; first by apply: hA. 
  exact: hAiB. 
Qed.

Lemma HilbertS2 : 
  C. 
Proof. 
  (* apply: hAiBiC; first by apply: hA. *)
  apply: hAiBiC. (* usually we think of : as pushing to the goal stack, so match c with conclusion in
  selected hypothesis hAiBiC and push the replacement, so put A & B in local context. *)
  by apply: hA. (* discharges A *)
  exact: hAiB.

End ssreflect1.
```

full script I was using. Why does that not put the hypothesis in the local context?

Comment: I think you might have some imports missing as the proof works for me on 8.15+1.14. You can try replacing `exact:` with `by apply:`, in both cases the actual proof term is `(hAiBiC hA (hAiB hA))`.

Comment: There is a maintained version of this kind of tutorials [here](https://github.com/math-comp/tutorial_material)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your example fails is probably that you did not open a section.  The various hypotheses that you declare are then treated as "axioms" and not in the context of the goal.

On the other hand, if you start a section before the fragment of text that you posted, everything works, because then the goal before the `exact: hAiB.` tactic also contains hypothesis `hA`, which is necessary for `exact:` to succeed.

Here is the full script (tested on coq 8.15.0)

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section sandbox.

Variables A B C : Prop.
Hypotheses (hAiBiC : A -> B -> C) (hAiB : A -> B) (hA : A).
Lemma HilbertS2 : 
  C. 
Proof. 
  apply: hAiBiC; first by apply: hA. 
  exact: hAiB. 
Qed.

End sandbox.
```

Comment: indeed the hypothesis are not put in the local context despite me having opened a `Module`. I suppose it must be that `Section` vs `Module` are not the same?

Comment: You are right, Section and modules are not the same with respect to context management.  Objects declared with `Variable` and `Hypothesis` become objects of the local context *only* if you are inside a section.  When the section is closed, all other objects that depend on the variables and hypothesis become functions with extra arguments.  This is a handy way to make a development depend on a common parameter.